# Save batch file path to local hard disk

Tags: file, batch-file

I have a batch file that runs when a self extracting file is executed.

The self extracting files must be copied to a specific directory on the hard disk.

In the batch file the user is asked where the path is (if it's not located in the default place).

Part of the batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF

IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\program\program.exe". (

    set PROGRAMPATH=C:\Program Files\

) ELSE (

    echo Program folder was not found. Please enter the path for Program

    set /p PROGRAMPATH=Path:
)

echo Copying data to "%PROGRAMPATH%"...


copy /Y "*.txt" "%PROGRAMPATH%"
```

Now for my question.

If a user then enters a new path, is it possible to save that path. So when he executes the self extracting file again, it could remember that new path?

Comment: You do know that there is an environment variable called `%ProgramFiles%` which saves you from having to hard-code the path?

Comment: ok, but I seems to have a problem because there is an "&" sign in the path.
Here is the path: C:\Program files\Prog & sample\
I have tried to save the path to the text file with quotes, but that didnt help either

Answer (score 1):

You can save the path to some file under %USERPROFILE% by doing

```
  echo %PROGRAMPATH% > "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\progpath.txt"
```

and then read it by doing

```
  set /p PROGRAMPATH=<"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\progpath.txt"
```

The full batch will look like this

```
@ECHO OFF

set PROGRAMPATH=C:\Program Files\

IF EXIST "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\progpath.txt". (
    set /p PROGRAMPATH=<%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\progpath.txt
)

IF NOT EXIST "%PROGRAMPATH%\program.exe". (
    echo Program folder was not found. Please enter the path for Program
    set /p PROGRAMPATH=Path:
)

echo %PROGRAMPATH%>"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\progpath.txt"

echo Copying data to "%PROGRAMPATH%"...
copy /Y "*.txt" "%PROGRAMPATH%"
```

Comment: Hi Ghostrider,
Thanks, it looks like it could do the trick.
But could you please show me were to put the lines?
It doesnt work for me, so maybe I have inserted the lines in the wrong places.

Comment: hmmm, it writes the path nicely to progpath.txt but it never uses it. It always ask's me for the PROGRAMPATH

Comment: Make sure that you are using built in Windows echo (rather than echo.exe that comes with cygwin or similar). It worked for me on Windows 7. YMMV

Comment: I've just notised one little issue.
If I have space in the PATH, nothing is written to the progpath.txt.
If I have no space in the PATH it works fine.
Do you know how to fix that? :o)